# Error while calculating Catalan number sequence

Tags: java, math, catalan

Whatever I tried this following code throws `ArithmeticException` with message  "Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result." on bigger numbers (like 43, 50, 56 etc).

Here is the code:

```
private BigDecimal catalan(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(4)
            .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(n))
            .subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(2))
            .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(n).add(BigDecimal.ONE))
            .multiply(new BigDecimal(catalan(n - 1)));
}
```

This method works flawlessly on small `n` numbers but when it comes to higher values it crashes.

Comment: Why isn't `n` also a `BigInteger`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Because the result after  divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(n).add(BigDecimal.ONE)) has important decimal point without which I cannot get correct result

Comment: Then why a `long`? It doesn't have decimal digits, and in the division you're converting it to a `BigDecimal` anyway.

Comment: That's correct, int can be used instead

Comment: @brack11 I don't understand how `BigDecimal`s ended up in your code at all. Catalan numbers are combinatorial entities, and always natural. All intermediate steps should also be carried out on natural numbers, e.g. `BigInteger`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exception occurs because of the line

```
.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(n).add(BigDecimal.ONE))
```

Here you did not give a precision scale, which means that it is possible to get an infinitely long decimal expansion, e.g when dividing 1 by 3.

To solve the error you need to put in a rounding scale and a rounding mode.

E.g:

```
.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(n).add(BigDecimal.ONE), 10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using BigDecimal is no help here, you have to perform the division AFTER you do the multiplication, in which case your algorithm works with BigInteger.

Comment: Well, you have to fix a few other bugs: new BigDecimal(catalan(n - 1)) should just be catalan(n - 1), and you should return BigDecimal.ONE instead of BigInteger.ONE